# Exporting in .dat format

Tags: export, code-review

I am new to *Mathematica*. I am trying to write the data of the plot of some function which I am using in a .dat format. I am using the following commands to do so:

```
Table[{r, f3}, {r, 0, 16, 0.1}]

Export["nontrivialprobablitydensityplotforg=0.05dat", data, "Table"]
```

But I am getting a .dat file which just has "data" written into it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `data` is not assigned...

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]
```

> `/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/yxc`

```
points = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, Range[0, 2 \[Pi], .01]}];
ListLinePlot[points]
```

[image]

```
Export["Export_Values_1.dat", points]
```

> `"Export_Values_1.dat"`

```
myTable = Table[{r, f3}, {r, 0, 16, 0.1}]
```

> `{{0.,f3},{0.1,f3},{0.2,f3},{0.3,f3},{0.4,f3},{0.5,f3},{0.6,f3},{0.7,f3},{0.8,f3},{0.9,f3},{1.,f3},{1.1,f3},{1.2,f3},{1.3,f3},{1.4,f3},{1.5,f3},{1.6,f3},{1.7,f3},{1.8,f3},{1.9,f3},{2.,f3},{2.1,f3},{2.2,f3},{2.3,f3},{2.4,f3},{2.5,f3},{2.6,f3},{2.7,f3},{2.8,f3},{2.9,f3},{3.,f3},{3.1,f3},{3.2,f3},{3.3,f3},{3.4,f3},{3.5,f3},{3.6,f3},{3.7,f3},{3.8,f3},{3.9,f3},{4.,f3},{4.1,f3},{4.2,f3},{4.3,f3},{4.4,f3},{4.5,f3},{4.6,f3},{4.7,f3},{4.8,f3},{4.9,f3},{5.,f3},{5.1,f3},{5.2,f3},{5.3,f3},{5.4,f3},{5.5,f3},{5.6,f3},{5.7,f3},{5.8,f3},{5.9,f3},{6.,f3},{6.1,f3},{6.2,f3},{6.3,f3},{6.4,f3},{6.5,f3},{6.6,f3},{6.7,f3},{6.8,f3},{6.9,f3},{7.,f3},{7.1,f3},{7.2,f3},{7.3,f3},{7.4,f3},{7.5,f3},{7.6,f3},{7.7,f3},{7.8,f3},{7.9,f3},{8.,f3},{8.1,f3},{8.2,f3},{8.3,f3},{8.4,f3},{8.5,f3},{8.6,f3},{8.7,f3},{8.8,f3},{8.9,f3},{9.,f3},{9.1,f3},{9.2,f3},{9.3,f3},{9.4,f3},{9.5,f3},{9.6,f3},{9.7,f3},{9.8,f3},{9.9,f3},{10.,f3},{10.1,f3},{10.2,f3},{10.3,f3},{10.4,f3},{10.5,f3},{10.6,f3},{10.7,f3},{10.8,f3},{10.9,f3},{11.,f3},{11.1,f3},{11.2,f3},{11.3,f3},{11.4,f3},{11.5,f3},{11.6,f3},{11.7,f3},{11.8,f3},{11.9,f3},{12.,f3},{12.1,f3},{12.2,f3},{12.3,f3},{12.4,f3},{12.5,f3},{12.6,f3},{12.7,f3},{12.8,f3},{12.9,f3},{13.,f3},{13.1,f3},{13.2,f3},{13.3,f3},{13.4,f3},{13.5,f3},{13.6,f3},{13.7,f3},{13.8,f3},{13.9,f3},{14.,f3},{14.1,f3},{14.2,f3},{14.3,f3},{14.4,f3},{14.5,f3},{14.6,f3},{14.7,f3},{14.8,f3},{14.9,f3},{15.,f3},{15.1,f3},{15.2,f3},{15.3,f3},{15.4,f3},{15.5,f3},{15.6,f3},{15.7,f3},{15.8,f3},{15.9,f3},{16.,f3}}`

```
Export["Export.dat", myTable]
```

> `"Export.dat"`